# HTML5 number input field goes up very fast in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

The issue I am having is on a booking form, where there are several number input fields. They have the up and down arrows which is fine, but when using the up arrow in Chrome, rather than going up by 1 it goes really easily up by several numbers at a time (without holding down the mouse).

Has anyone else experienced this? Is there a fix for it other than hiding it in Chrome?

Thanks

To add, here is the full code with event handler:

```
        $(".product_holder input").bind('keyup change click', function (e) {

            if ($('#startDate').val() != "" && $('#endDate').val() != "") {
                if (!$(this).data("previousValue") || $(this).data("previousValue") != $(this).val()     ) {


                    if ($(this).is("[max]") && ( $(this).val() >= $(this).attr('max') ) )
                    {
                        if (! $(this).parent().find(".validwarnning").length > 0)
                        {
                            $(this).parent().append("<div class='validwarnning'>The maximum number has been reached</div>");
                        }
                        $(this).val($(this).attr('max'));
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        $(this).data("previousValue", $(this).val());
                        //$(this).parent
                        $thisProduct = $(this).parent();
                        WriteItemRow($thisProduct);

                        updateTableTotal();
                    }

                }
            }
            else
            {
                $('#startDate').addClass("error_input");
                $('#endDate').addClass("error_input");
                $('#dateError').html("Please select your dates first");
                $(this).val("0");

            }

        });
```

Comment: can you post the relevant code on here, or point us to a online demo so we can experience?

Comment: Have you attached any event handler to that input?

Comment: I can't recreate the problem, when i click 1 time on the up arrow, the value goes up 1. Could you please upload your code if it is different than this: https://jsfiddle.net/310c7fn0/

Comment: Here's the code: <input type="number" id="num_electricity" name="qty_electricity" value="0" min="0" class="qty type_extra ui-state-valid" max="9"> 

When clicking on the arrow up once (from 0) without moving my mouse it keeps going up continuously. Only when I move my mouse the number stops. It then does not happen on subsequent up or down clicks.

I have tried this on another pc as well and had the same issue (both with PC + chrome)

Comment: I have added the code in the original question - many thanks!

Comment: Any chance you are using python debug toolbar? I had this issue and tracked it down to some javascript that was included with that package.

Answer (score 0):

You should include a step attribute on the input tag `step='1'`

Comment: I've just tried that but unfortunately did not make a difference.

Comment: Can you post the html?

Comment: <input type="number" id="num_adults" step="1" name="qty_adults" value="2" min="0" class="qty" required="" max="2">

Comment: @MayorMonty why should this be a comment? It is a short answer, but that does not mean it is _Not An Answer_. [Please see this post.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)